# What are the design considerations behind exempting WebSockets from the SOP?

Tags: same-origin-policy, cors, websocket

I was rather surprised that in my experiments, I could simply connect from one website to a WebSocket server on a different domain/port pair. Subsequent research repeatedly showed that WebSockets do not fall under the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), so this makes sense.

However - *why is the WebSocket standard defined this way?*

It seems that there are two opposite approaches used on the web:

- HTTP: unless the Web server has a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) configuration, (certain) cross-origin requests are prevented by the browser, i.e. it's an opt-in, deny policy.
- WS: unless the WebSocket server checks the origin header, cross-origin requests are possible, i.e. it's an opt-out, allow policy.

As WebSocket is younger than HTTP, is it just a historical thing and WS is doing it correctly? If so, what's suboptimal about CORS? Or otherwise, what was the rationale here?

Comment: SOP is primarily about protecting copyright; preventing untraceable client-side-only mashups that strip ads and deep-link content above and beyond images. WS is by def opt-in, so implementations are aware of what they give away and who can connect. In terms of security, WS doesn't execute content like HTML does, so the same risks (xss, etc) don't apply. WS is made for web services, and as such, allowing 3rd party embedding is a critical part of it's utility; we could already use COMET or http long-polling on same domains for years...

Comment: @dandavis "_SOP is primarily about protecting copyright_" Do you have a source for that?

Comment: See [Why is there no same-origin policy for WebSockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37837709/816620)

Comment: @curiousguy: my characterization as a dinosaur-era webdev. Consider the 2nd-half of [this description from the W3](https://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy#Network_Access): "_The prohibition on receiving information is intended to prevent malicious web sites from reading confidential information from other web sites, but also prevents web content from legitimately reading information offered by other web sites._" "Confidential info" on a website can be easily plucked by CURL/etc, SOP!=infosec, which leaves the anti-mashup aspect; the part that happens to protect content sources...